# Redirect to a JSP page after login using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, jquery

I have a login.jsp page where users type in username and password. Username and password are sent to the server using ajax ($.post). When the authentication is complete, I want to redirect user to an index.jsp page.

js:

```
function Login()
{
    var traderName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var traderPass = document.getElementById('password').value;

    //SetLoginLoading();

    data = {action:'login',username:traderName,password:traderPass};

    $.post('TraderServlet',$.param(data),function(response){
    });
    return false;
}
```

Servlet

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              ....
              login(request, response);
              ....
     }       
   private void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME);
        String pass = request.getParameter(PARAMETER_PASS);
        traderBean.login(name, pass);

        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
```

I tried to use response.sendRedirect() but it does not work. Should I use jQuery to redirect user using ajaxCallback ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think you should try to use a client-side redirect in your ajax callback.

Comment: If you will use ajax requests, make sure to change the response content to text and write a JSON String with the content of your response to handle the results in the client side. You can have a simple structure like `{ "resultCode": "0", "errorMessage" : "" }` or similar, but that depends on your functional requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you are just going to redirect anyway, there is really no point in using AJAX as you can accomplish this by just having the servlet handle directly from the form.

To your question, first check the url pattern of your servlet. Make sure it is actually being called. If so, then if it has a url pattern like

`/TraderServlet`

Then it expects `index.jsp` to be also in the root folder under `Web`. It could be that you are simply not redirecting to where you are expecting to go.

One way to check is (if you're in Chrome) use the debugger tools (F12 on Windows/Nix, Ctrl-Shift-I on Macs), and see what error it is giving.